# How to export Blender content in online stores?

Tags: animation

I am making few models which include animations and textures. I would like to upload these in sites such as BlenderMarket and TurboSquid for selling. I would like to know how to do this especially the animations. Should I upload the models separately and is there a way to upload the animations effects separately. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at site like TurboSquid you may see that each model has more than one file format. That means you need to export your finished model more than one time with different format each time. That might give you an idea about how to start with uploading. If I were you, I would check some samples from sites like TurboSquid to understand how people exported animation files to begin with.